# DataGridView freezes when loading content and style C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, styles, freeze

My form has 6 dataGridViews in different tabs of a tab Control, the user is able to enter values and change the cell backcolor, with a save button, the values for each dataGridView are saved into a text file, same with the backcolor of the cells in each dataGridView. When the user re-opens the form, all the last settings(style and values) are loaded again to the 6 dataGridViews; The problem is that when the user re-opens the form, the dataGridViews freeze and I don't find a way to fix that. Can someone help me?

My loading data and style code:

```
 foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(stylePath))
        {
            string[] items = s.Split(';');
            if (items.Length == 3)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(items[0])]
                   .Cells[Convert.ToInt32(items[1])]
                   .Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(items[2]));
            }
        }
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(valuePath);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Value = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
```

Here is how it looks when re-opening the form:
[image]

Comment: chris: we need to see some code to understand where it does freeze

Comment: please edit/add the part where you re-open, read from file, update the gridViews

Comment: @chouaib I noticed something more, if I don't run the LoadStyle void, then the dataGridView did not freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stylePath))
{
   string line;
   string[] items;
   int row, cell;
   Color color;

   while(!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
      line = sr.ReadLine();
      items = line.Split(';');
      if(items.Length<3) continue; //something wrong in the file

      row = Convert.ToInt32(items[0]);
      cell = Convert.ToInt32(items[1]);

      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item[2])) continue; // No change is needed
      color = Color.FromName(items[2]);

      dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Style.BackColor = color;
   }
}
```

Comment: The code worked, the colors appear, but the other cells still look like transparent.(I can see through them) PS: with other cells, I refer to the cells that had no change.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss: I guess they had no changes because they have no settings! even if you read the `stylePath` file with text editor I am sure there is no setting for them. right?

Comment: to what are you refering with "settings"

Comment: for example you have `0, 0, red` `0, 1, blue` as settings of `rows[0].cells[0] = red` and `rows[0].cells[1] = blue`, but you don't have lines of text that translate to settings of the other cells. This was my question

Comment: Oh, you gave me a code in a previous question, which writes the number of column + row + color; my output is 0;0; 0;1; 0;2;Red; 0;3; etc

Comment: how many cells you have per one row? and give me the first line in your `stylePath` text file

Comment: I have 9 cells per row, but just 6 of them can be backColor changed; the first line of the stylePath file is 0;0;

Comment: ah sorry, since you have 9cells/row, please give me the first 9 lines I need to check them

Comment: 0;0;
0;1;
0;2;
0;3;
0;4;
0;5;
0;6;
0;7;
0;8;

Comment: I guess there is a mistake somewhere, the lines should be `0;0;red` `0;1;blue` ... etc ?

Comment: Yes but that's the output when I haven't changed the backColor

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss, very glad it helped you ;)